# It is necessary to take data from a table that is generated automatically and there is no model and no repository for it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have a Student model

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable (name="student_university",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn (name="student_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="university_id"))
    private List<University> universities;
```

And the University model

```
@Entity
public class University {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="student_university",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="university_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="student_id"))
    private List<Student> students;
```

I get 2 models and 2 repositories. Since the connection is ManyToMany, the 3 table is automatically generated. How can I get data from this new table if there is no model and repository for it? Perhaps you can write a request somehow from the controller and pass the result to the template?

SQL Student
[image]

University SQL
[image]

student_university SQL
[image]

Comment: You could use SQL. The question is why do you want to query this table as there are only two foreign keys.

Comment: Can you show how to write sql queries in the controller and pass the result to the template? I don't understand how to do this

Comment: I need to make an addition form, after which the data from this form will be saved to this table. There will be 2 drop-down lists. In 1, I choose a student, and in the second, a university

Comment: There is no need to query this intermediate table to accomplish the "addition form" you describe in your comment above. You can work with your entities Student and University

Comment: How can I work with them? I inserted SQL into my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that since you are using spring-boot you already have created the relevant JpaRepositories for your entities, e.g. `studentRepository` and `universityRepository`.

Load the selected (in the drop down list) Student and University from the database e.g.
Lets assume the selected student from the drop down list has #id: 10 and the selected university from the other drop down list has #id: 45

```
Long studentId = 10L; //retrieve the real value from your controller's request
Student student = studentRepository.findById(studentId);

Long univerityId = 45L; //retrieve the real value from your controller's request
University univeristy = universityRepository.findById(univerityId);
```

then add the university to the student's university list and save to DB

```
student.getUniversities().add(university); //make sure your university list is not null else you will get a null pointer exception here
university.getStudents().add(student); // you can also add the student to the university's students list
studentRepository.save(student);
```

Upon saving the `student_university` table should have a new record with the ids of the student and the university.